# How to repair site permissions after incorrect chown command?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I was trying to install a PHP application and it required extra permissions on my web hosting server so I ran the command `chown dan:dan -R` and it has totally knocked my sites offline. I get this error no matter what pages or sites I go to under that server:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have never used .htaccess files and the server was setup I guess to not need them, I believe it's Apache and running on Linux with Godaddy.

How can I revert the command entered?

Comment: The correct permissions depend on your server and Apache configuration. Are you using a shared server? If so, what user does Apache run under? You need to be especially careful that you do not grant read access to your cookie files, or write access to your projects, to other customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some simple easy steps here that could save you some time and effort, Let me know how you get on because this is not a guaranteed fix, Your question is rather open and therefore not specifically detailed in what could be the issue.

try:
cd /home/your_username_here as /home/dandan is the folder before public_html

Example:   `cd /home/dandan`

then run
`cat .htaccess or  cat .htaccess.bak`  depending on your setup.

see if the output looks like this:

```
<Directory>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

if not then edit the file to be the same as the above and this should work.

If this does not work you can try the following command:

chmod 750 (foldername) so the example would be:

```
chmod 750 mywebsite.com
```

its more secure than running chmod 777 because if someone got access to your server 777 means they can read, write and execute

Comment: Thanks this worked instantly.  I changed the folder rules to 750 and added the .htaccess file and it worked right away. Thanks for your help :)